# How to do Client side validation without using model in mvc 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 application in which I am not using the View Models and don't want to use them. For the Models I am using the classes which are generated from the Entities. Please tell me that is there any way to do this.

Comment: yes I can use jQuery Plugins.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to specify the validation attributes (if you want ASP to handle the validation for you.) You can use a partial class to extend your Models and then add the attributes like this:

```
//this is the model (generated from the entities)  
   [MetadataType(typeof(User_Validation))]

    public partial class User
    {

    }
```

Then specify the validation properties.

```
    public class User_Validation
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="The Full Name is required")]
        public string FullName{ get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="The Cellphone Number  is required")]
        public string CellNumber { get; set; }

    }
```

Or, you can handle all the validation yourself using jQuery or other client side plugin of your choice.

Comment: This. I find it a bit safer to use an interface as the metadata type, that way (1) your classes are interfaced so testing is easy, (2) any changes to the model will automatically break your interface at compile time, so you can fix it right away.

Comment: I didn't get you completely, suppose in my View I am using "@ model Home.Client.Contact" and here Contact is the "Contact.generated.cs" file, which is generated from the Entities, So in my case there will be a public class Contact_Validation{....} according to you, So I want to know that how View will recognize this Contact_Validation..??

Comment: The XXX_Validation class is there to specify validation attributes only. It is linked to the model via the `[MetadataType(typeof(User_Validation))]` attribute (just above) the model. You wont need to reference it in the View.

Comment: So do I have to define this User_Validation class just below the partial class User, which is generated by the Entities or do I have to define this in some other file.

Comment: You can put them in one file, it doesnt matter.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't recognize the .DataAnnotations namespace when I used this with the "using" statement in the generated.cs file, then I copied this file at some other location and write this code there were no errors in the file but there were some Type Casting issues.So what to do so that it recognize the .DataAnnotations namespace..?

Comment: Oh, you need to add a reference (Right click your project, click 'Add reference', and add System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.)

Answer (score 1):

Decorate your form elements with jQuery validation attributes (normally done automatically by MVC when it reads your model's DataAnnotations).

From the docs, this is how you would do a simple textbox validation:

`<input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />`

Then,

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#commentForm").validate();
  });`

see [jQuery validation documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) for more

Comment: I used this but it's not working. Do I have to do other changes also apart from these..??

Comment: you will need to ensure that your form submission is wrapped by the validation js stuff. Check for JS errors, and try calling $(<form id, name, etc>).validate() in your browser console to experiment.